# android: get items from string array and show it one by one in text view

Tags: android, xml, arrays, sharedpreferences

as i write in title i need some help here for get items from string array and show it one by one in text view i have code that got them all in list view but i need show them on text view one by one each time random here my code and sorry about my bad english
,thanks for help anyway ...

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] mTestArray;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter that will contain all list items
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        mTestArray =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);    

        /* Assign the name array to that adapter and 
        also choose a simple layout for the list items */ 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mTestArray);

        // Assign the adapter to this ListActivity
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@array/planets_array"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and string array file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: you want them to be shown randomly or in sequence ?

Comment: Pls. check my ans. and if your question is answered pls. accept the ans. :)

Comment: You don't want a listView, right? Only a textView to show your array values randomly in it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, with comments I understood what you need and edited my answer for that. You want to show values of your array in a textView randomly.

Use this activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] mTestArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);

        mTestArray =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);    

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateTextView();
    }

    private void updateTextView() {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomTextView); 
        Random random = new Random();

        int maxIndex = mTestArray.length;
        int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);

        textView.setText(mTestArray[generatedIndex]);   
    }
}
```

Put this layout under res/layout folder and name it sample.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/randomTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for help about it, yes i would like make it show random value each time app start and when app run again its give another random value i hope you understand what

Comment: So you don't want a listView?

Comment: no i dont need list view all i need Text View show 1 random value from string array each time i run this app .. thanks for reply :)

Comment: Then extend from Activity not ListActivity. Set content of your activity a layout which has a textView(or directly a textView). And use the code at my answer to get random index. Then use that index to get a random array item. Set that array item's text to your textView. Thats all.

Comment: thanks for your help i l will leave this point its really tired me i will find other way sorry im still new in android develop side :)

Comment: I see. I updated my answer with your comments. Hope that helps. BTW try to ask your question more careful. I was realy hard to understand what you were looking for:)

Comment: Thank you so much for you kind and your answer , my english little bit bad and im still beginner in android i appreciate your help thankss